# Generic LINQ Function throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." but DbSet<T> and DbContext are initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to query `DbSet<T>` using a generic function but any attempt to do so throws **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."** error but when I use DbContext instance, it works. May I know what am I doing wrong, I have wired up everything else correctly.

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
        private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;

         private readonly AppDbContext context;

         public GenericRepository(AppDbContext _context)
         {
            context = _context;

            dbSet = context.Set<T>();
         }

        //Function throwing Error

        public Task<List<T>> GetListAsync(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> include = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            Expression<Func<T, object>> distinctBy = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

            if (predicate != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(predicate);
            }

            if (distinctBy != null)
            {
                query = query.Distinct(distinctBy);
            }

            if (include != null)
            {
                query = include(query);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToListAsync();
            }

            return query.ToListAsync();
        }

}
```

Below is the code consuming the generic function

```
public class EmployeeAssetServiceRepository : GenericRepository<EmployeeAssetService>, IEmployeeAssetServiceRepository
{
        private ResponseHelper Response;

        private ResultCode ResultCode { get; set; }

        private ResponseMessage Message { get; set; }

        private readonly AppDbContext context;

        public EmployeeAssetServiceRepository(AppDbContext _context) : base(_context)
        {
            context = _context;

            Response = new ResponseHelper();

             Message = new ResponseMessage();
        }

        public async Task<ResponseHelper> GetAllAsync()
        {
            List<EmployeeAssetService> recordList = new List<EmployeeAssetService>();

            try
            {
                recordList = await GetListAsync(
                    predicate: null,
                    include: e => e.Include(i => i.Assignment.Employee)
                    .Include(i => i.Assignment.Employee.Title)
                    .Include(i => i.Assignment.Employee.Department),
                    orderBy: e => e.OrderBy(o => o.Assignment.Employee.LastName)
                    .ThenBy(o => o.Assignment.Employee.FirstName),
                    distinctBy: e => e.Assignment.Employee.Id);

                 /*context.EmployeeAssetService
                    .Include(i => i.Assignment.Employee)
                    .Include(i => i.Assignment.Employee.Title)
                    .Include(i => i.Assignment.Employee.Department)
                    .Distinct(d => d.Assignment.Employee.Id)
                    .OrderBy(o => o.Assignment.Employee.LastName)
                    .ThenBy(o => o.Assignment.Employee.FirstName)
                    .ToListAsync();*/

                Message.Success = string.Format(EnumDescription
                        .GetEnumDescription(ResultCode.ReadAllMessage),
                        nameof(EmployeeAssetService).InsertSpace());

                ResultCode = ResultCode.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return ResponseHelper.ExceptionResponse(nameof(EmployeeAssetServiceRepository), nameof(Employee            AssetServiceRepository.GetAllAsync), e);
            }

            return ResponseHelper.CreateResponse(ResultCode, Message, recordList);
        }

}
```

Comment: Where is the NRE caused by? Did you notice you have your includes/distinct/orderby in different order in the context query vs your generic method? Even though you call the GetListAsync with named parameters does not mean they are executed in that order.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Hi, thank you very much, the problem was the order of execution, I moved include command below the predicate and voalá it worked as expected.

Comment: Most likely the problem is caused by the custom `Distinct` method, because  `Include` and `Where` methods order doesn't matter.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for the highlight, I noticed that ```Where``` clause should be executed before ```Distinct``` otherwise the Result Set would be wrong. So, order of query execution is important.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently I had the order of execution wrong as pointed out by @JanneMatikainen, I have moved the include command below the predicate and now this works.

```
public Task<List<T>> GetListAsync(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null,
        Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> include = null,
        Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
        Expression<Func<T, object>> distinctBy = null)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

        if (predicate != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(predicate);
        }

        if (include != null)
        {
            query = include(query);
        }

        if (distinctBy != null)
        {
            query = query.Distinct(distinctBy);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToListAsync();
        }

        return query.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: This line `query = query.Distinct(distinctBy);` gives an error.